# Having problems getting a 4TB drive to work on Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit) on an ASUS Maximus III Formula motherboard

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bsod

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit) on an [ASUS Maximus III Formula](https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/MAXIMUS_III_FORMULA/specifications/) motherboard. The PC is self built so it has the parts I put in it.

I downloaded Seagate DiscWizard to install this drive here:

- [Seagate 4TB Desktop HDD SATA 6Gb/s NCQ 64MB Cache 3.5-Inch Internal Bare Drive ST4000DM000](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B99JU4S)

I screwed up and formated it to the 1.7TB size, after formating I got a blue screen of death.

Then I unplugged it and began researching how to get its 4TB’s. I downloaded Seagate’s DiscWizard and formated the drive from the wizard on a CD disk during bootup.

Any time the drive is plugged in Windows will not boot and if I plug the SATA cable in after a few minutes I get a blue screen of death.

Is the drive bad? Do I have some wrong driver? Or is my system incompatible for some reason?

The drive is currently formated to 3.7TB with GPT, but halts windows at the initial windows logo screen on bootup. If I unplug the drive at this point it will load windows, otherwise just sits there. If I plug in the SATA cable after it has booted, after a few minutes when the drive is being recognized, it crashes to a blue screen.

Comment: Can you give us more information. Like the make/model of machine or motherboard where the SATA controller exists.

Comment: "Is this the result of DRM anti piracy software?" - This isn't the reason you are having this problem.  It is more likely your SATA controller does not have support for a drive this large, and/or, based on the 1.7TB size you did select, you are using a MBR partition type instead of GPT.

Comment: I have added a bunch new drivers to my hardware, because they were badly outdated anyway.  I tend to avoid updating many things unless I run into a problem.  Specifically the SATA drivers, but I wonder if I got the right drivers?

Comment: Motherboard specs.  https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/MAXIMUS_III_FORMULA/

Comment: Since the HDD size is properly recognized in BIOS it could be a problem with the motherboard chipset driver. Look for the latest driver available for the chipset. Just as a precaution you can try using a different SATA port as well. I also recommend that you download the manufacturer diagnostics tool and run a scan of the HDD to confirm its health status.

Comment: The problem for me has been finding the driver on Intel's site.  I spent an hour or two looking.  Downloaded a tool that was supposed to help me find the driver, but apparently it was the wrong utility.  I am not certain there was a means with the Disc Wizard to check if the HDD was ok.  I can't say I saw the option.  What tool is there to do this from bootup?

Comment: It could be a separate utility, try googling for the HDD manufacturer testing tool for DOS.

Comment: Someone on here might find this link useful.  http://www.ultimatebootcd.com    Still haven't managed to fix the disk.  Right now it seems moving my DVD writers to the optical drive controller altered their role in booting.  I tried to alter this in bios, but for some reason it didn't work as planned.

Comment: I have been unable to find the proper software.  The one I downloaded is an ISO file and doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: So I figured out I basically needed burner software to get the file here to burn correctly to a disk.  I get it burned, it boots my pc, but apparently my mouse does not work in it like other boot programs and I am back to square one.  Nor do keyboard commands appear to work.  http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/item/seatools-dos-master/

Comment: What version of the BIOS are you running? There's a 2202 version which is supposed to "support full HDD capacity." (You'll need the driver in that file to install in Windows too)

Comment: Uninstall Seagate DiscWizard. Update SATA drivers. Clean disk using any Linux live CD. Done